# Watch Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

```
Webpack: Starting ...
ui/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:104
    throw new _ValidationError.default(errors, schema, configuration);
    ^

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Watch Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. {
  schema: {
    title: 'WatchIgnorePluginOptions',
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      paths: {
        description: 'A list of RegExps or absolute paths to directories or files that should be ignored.',
        type: 'array',
        items: {
          description: 'RegExp or absolute path to directories or files that should be ignored.',
          anyOf: [ [Object], [Object] ]
        },
        minItems: 1
      }
    },
    required: [ 'paths' ]
  },
  headerName: 'Watch Ignore Plugin',
  baseDataPath: 'options',
  postFormatter: null
}
```

It is thrown with the following configuration:

```
new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([ 'src/test' ])
```

The version of webpack is "^5.0.0-rc.6".
According to constructor

```
constructor(paths: Array<string | RegExp>)
```

`[ 'src/test' ]` should be fine. Where I did a mistake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I got the answer from this [issue](https://github.com/nestjs/docs.nestjs.com/issues/1554).

The WatchIgnorePlugin options should be converted to

```
new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({paths: [ 'src/test' ]})
```

Comment: Then how resolve the below warning when calling `new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin({paths: [ 'src/test' ]})` from js:

`Argument type {paths: [string]} is not assignable to parameter type Array<string | RegExp>`